# document.cookie not saving cookies unless I include ;SameSite=None; Secure

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I tried using `document.cookie` to store user info to pass to another page as a test.

Here is how it's being stored

```
document.cookie = "userName=" + userName + ";SameSite=None; Secure"
```

Here is how it is being read on the page redirected to from the form:

```
console.log("cookies", document.cookie)
```

However, it does not work in firefox or chrome when testing locally. Only when I include the following with the cookie does it work locally only in firefox.

```
;SameSite=None; Secure
```

You can even hardcode the urlParams and it still won't store the cookie.

The documentation does not speak to this online from what I read.

Below here is the full code sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <title>Interests Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="top">
            <a class="logo" href="index.html">CapellaVolunteers<span class="dotcom">.org</span></a>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul class="topnav">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="invitation.html">Invitation</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="registration.html" class="active">Registration</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </nav>
    </header>
    <section id="pageForm">
        <form action="confirm.html">
            Choose your interests from the following options:
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="running" name="running">
                <label for="running">Running</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="modelPlanes" name="modelPlanes">
                <label for="modelPlanes">Model Planes</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="basketball" name="basketball">
                <label for="basketball">Basketball</label>
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="signUpNewsletter">Sign up for newsletter:
                </label>
                <input type="radio" name="signUpNewsletter" value="Yes"> Yes
                <input type="radio" name="signUpNewsletter" value="No"> No
            </div>

            <div>
                <div>Put your comments here</div>
                <textarea></textarea>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="referredBy">Referred by:
                </label>
                <input type="text" name="referredBy" placeholder="Referred by name goes here" />
            </div>


            <input type="hidden" name="userName" />
            <input type="hidden" name="password" />
            <input type="hidden" name="passwordVerify" />
            <input type="hidden" name="firstName" />
            <input type="hidden" name="lastName" />
            <input type="hidden" name="email" />
            <input type="hidden" name="phoneNumber" />
            <input type="hidden" name="signUpNewsletter" />

            <input type="submit" value="Register">
        </form>
    </section>

    <footer>This events site is for IT-FP3215 tasks.
    </footer>
</body>
<script>

    /* Interests (list at least three using a checkbox).
    Newsletter sign up (radio box with a yes/no option).
    Comments (free form text area).
    Referred by (text field). */
    window.onload = function () {

        document.forms[0].onsubmit = function (event) {
            var url = new URL(window.location.href);
            var userName = url.searchParams.get("userNameHidden");
            var password = url.searchParams.get("passwordHidden");
            var passwordVerify = url.searchParams.get("passwordVerifyHidden");
            var firstName = url.searchParams.get("firstNameHidden");
            var lastName = url.searchParams.get("lastNameHidden");
            var email = url.searchParams.get("emailHidden");
            var phoneNumber = url.searchParams.get("phoneNumberHidden");
            var signUpNewsletter = url.searchParams.get("signUpNewsletterHidden")

            document.cookie = "userName=" + userName + ";SameSite=None; Secure"
            document.cookie = "password=" + password + ";SameSite=None; Secure"

            console.log(document.cookie)
        }

    }
</script>

</html>
```

I have read it may be because Chrome doesn't store cookies unless you are using a server? This is just a series of static js files right now while testing

Can anyone assist? Thanks!